# Can't render html tags in a template string in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Googled it but still can't realize how to render html tags in a template string in React:

```
return (
  <p className="text-left m-3">
     {this.state.movies ? `Showing <strong>`${this.state.movies.length}</strong`> : 
                          `DB is empty`
     }
  </p>
);
```

Is there any elegant "react way" to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply make use of `span` to wrap the elements instead of having them returned as a string

```
return (
  <p className="text-left m-3">
     {this.state.movies ? <span>Showing <strong>{this.state.movies.length}</strong></span> : 
                          <span>DB is empty</span>
     }
  </p>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Few things you are doing wrong in your code.
1. Template literals do not work directly in return, you need to add template literals inside {`test ${value}`}
2. You have syntax error here i.e., template literal should end after ending tag element of strong

```
 `Showing <strong>`${this.state.movies.length}</strong`>
```

Do it this way

```
return (
  <p className="text-left m-3">
     {this.state.movies ? <span>{`Showing <strong>${this.state.movies.length}</strong>`}</span> : 
                          <span>{`DB is empty`}</span>
     }
  </p>
);
```

OR

Assign template literals to a local variable and call it in return

```
render(){
   const text = `Showing <strong>${this.state.movies.length}</strong>`;
   const text1 = `DB is empty`;
   return (
     <p className="text-left m-3">
     {this.state.movies ? <span>{text}</span> : <span>{text1}</span>}
     </p>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like this:

```
return (
  <p className="text-left m-3">
     Showing 
   {this.state.movies &&
    // I would also make sure its length
     this.state.movies.length > 0 &&
     // to make sure not to print 0
     <strong>this.state.movies.length</strong> 
     || 'DB is empty'}
  </p>
);
```